# i18n not providing translation for french text with accents in C# code

Tags: .net-core, internationalization

We have a .NET core application in french with i18n to translate in english.
There is one unwanted behavior for which we didn't find a solution : for each text containing accents (like "é") in C# code, i18n doesn't provide the translated msgstr and just show the default language msgid.

For example in my .po file :

```
#: Views\User\Index.cshtml:58
msgid "Compte bloqué"
msgstr "Blocked account"
```

This will work if it's :

- in plain HTML
- in javascript/jquery

This will not work if it's :

- in Razor code (ActionLink, etc...)
- in Model/Controller

i18n sees that it has to translate it since we don't see the [[[ ]]] around the text, but it just doesn't provide the chosen translation and doesn't generate an error. We thought it might be an encoding problem, but each file is in utf-8 (with or without BOM, no difference).

The .pot file header :

```
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: \n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2022-10-04 15:13+02:00\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"X-Generator: pot (1.0.16)\n"
```

Here's how we set i18n in Startup.cs :

```
    services.AddI18NLocalization(_webHostEnvironment, options =>
    {
        var supportedCultures = new[]
        {
            new CultureInfo("fr-FR"),
            new CultureInfo("en-US")
        };

        var defaultCulture = supportedCultures.Single(x => x.Name == "fr-FR");

        options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(defaultCulture);
        options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
        options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
        options.RequestCultureProviders = new List<IRequestCultureProvider>
        {
            new CookieRequestCultureProvider()
        };
    });
```

The only thing that is working so far is using a variable in code and write the text with the accents in the msgstr of the .pot file. But it's not a viable solution since it's the template, and every msgstr is reset when i18n makes a change to the file.

So of course we tried to make a .po file for fr-FR (default language), but although it's generated just fine, everything is ignored inside, msgid isn't replaced with the chosen msgstr.

Any idea?

Comment: Did you also try `"fr"` (French, not necessarily France)?

Comment: Yes @JoopEggen, I tried again just in case, but no changes.